# Turn on the keyboard backlight with Night Light mode?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-backlight

Is it possible to turn on the keyboard backlight automatically when the Night Light is activated?

Comment: Excellent suggestion!!! +1 also it will save keyboard battery in day time when lights are wasted.

Answer (score 0):

Of course , In my laptop (Lenovo ideapad 700) I use Night light and I turn on my keyboard backlight with `fn + space` keys and as far as I know these two features are not related

Comment: Maybe I need to rephrase my question. I want the keyboard backlight to turn on automatically when the Night Light is activated. I will edit the question now.